# Installing .cls files in TeXLive without using the command window

Tags: directory

I need to let my TeXLive for Mac distribution see a .cls file inside the following directory (only last part of the path reported):

\local\tex\latex\myclass

I know there are many answers to this question, but as far as I have been able to see they all suggest to use a shell command such as mktexlsr.

Is there a way to do what I want via a graphical interface, without using the command window?